# Magento API V2 Front End Label not defined. Creating Additional Attribute

Tags: api, magento, c#-4.0

i am creating additional attribute through Magento API V2, i am unable to set frontend label, if i create attribute without frontend label it creates attribute and frontend label is same as attribute code, but when is set custom text for frontend label it gives error "Front end label not defined"

here is my code

```
 private void btnCreateAdditionalAttrib_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            sessionID = MagentoConnectivity.connectMagento();
            string[] applyto = new string[1];
            applyto[0] = "simple";

            List<associativeEntity> thentities = new List<associativeEntity>
        {
            new associativeEntity { key = "store_id", value = "0" } ,
            new associativeEntity { key = "label", value = txtAttributeName.Text } 
        };

            catalogProductAttributeFrontendLabelEntity[] myFronendLabel = new catalogProductAttributeFrontendLabelEntity[2];



            myFronendLabel[0] = new catalogProductAttributeFrontendLabelEntity { label = "store_id", store_id = "1" };
            myFronendLabel[1] = new catalogProductAttributeFrontendLabelEntity { label = "label", store_id = txtAttributeName.Text };

            catalogProductAttributeEntityToCreate newAttribute = new catalogProductAttributeEntityToCreate
            {
                attribute_code = txtAttributeCode.Text,
                frontend_input = "text",
                scope = "1",
                default_value = "1",
                is_unique = 0,
                is_required = 0,
                apply_to = applyto,
                is_configurable = 0,
                is_searchable = 0,
                is_visible_in_advanced_search = 0,
                is_comparable = 0,
                is_used_for_promo_rules = 0,
                is_visible_on_front = 0,
                used_in_product_listing = 0,
                frontend_label = myFronendLabel

            };


            int x = MagentoConnectivity.magService.catalogProductAttributeCreate(sessionID, newAttribute);

            MessageBox.Show(x + "");
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(exp.Message + "\n\n\n" + exp);
        }
    }
```

// Here is PHP Example

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttribute/product_attribute.create.html

```
    Request Example SOAP V2

<?php
//ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);

$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');

//V2
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

// V2 WS-I Mode
//$response = $client->login(array('username' => 'apiUser', 'apiKey' => 'apiKey'));
//$session = $response->result;


//v2

$data = array(
   "attribute_code" => "test_attribute",
   "frontend_input" => "text",
   "scope" => "1",
   "default_value" => "1",
   "is_unique" => 0,
   "is_required" => 0,
   "apply_to" => array("simple"),
   "is_configurable" => 0,
   "is_searchable" => 0,
   "is_visible_in_advanced_search" => 0,
   "is_comparable" => 0,
   "is_used_for_promo_rules" => 0,
   "is_visible_on_front" => 0,
   "used_in_product_listing" => 0,
   "additional_fields" => array(),
   "frontend_label" => array(array("store_id" => "0", "label" => "some label"))
  );

$orders = $client->catalogProductAttributeCreate($session, $data);



//V2 WSI
//WSDL WSI Sample is not complete
//$result = $client->catalogProductAttributeCreate(array("sessionId" => $session, "data" => $data));
//$orders = $result->result->complexObjectArray;

echo 'Number of results: ' . count($orders) . '<br/>';
var_dump ($orders);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indexed array.

```
// app/code/Magento/Eav/Model/Resource/Entity/Attribute.php":207

$frontendLabel = $object->getFrontendLabel();
if (is_array($frontendLabel)) {
    $frontendLabel = array_values($frontendLabel); // add this line
    if (!isset($frontendLabel[0]) || is_null($frontendLabel[0]) || $frontendLabel[0] == '') {
        throw new \Magento\Core\Exception(__('Frontend label is not defined'));
    }
```

You can see more detail in [this pull request](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/531).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space. Change `some label` to `some_label`.